# What does this code do in Spring Boot custom type level annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm previously looking around for code to get my type level custom annotation to work ( previously it doesn't validate or show error message ) I added this code and it worked but I have no idea what it does. If you can explain it I would really appreciate it!

Code in question. Message is the error message, mm is the variable I choose to display the error message. Usually my type level annotation compares a few variables so the error message only appears under one of the variable.

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
                    .addPropertyNode("mm").addConstraintViolation();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.ConstraintViolationBuilder.NodeContextBuilder.html), it says.

> It Adds a property node to the path the `ConstraintViolation` will be associated to.

So that means if `mm` is not valid, it will show `message`. Also note that this method is deprecated.